# Meauring voltage from a DC 15kV - 50kV source with around 1 microampere of current

Tags: amplifier, adc, high-voltage

I am building a DC energy generating device that at the moment generated DC power at 15K-50k Volts at 1 microampere.

I am considering using a high impedance ADC (1G ohm, 0.3V range, 2 nanoamperes current, 32 bits.)

When I plan out a voltage divider circuit to work with this ADC my voltage or current is always out of range.

I would ideally like to tune my circuit so current is between 0-0.3V and I have 2 nanoamperes for the ADC to sample.  It also requires a very expensive 100G ohm or more resistor.

Is there a way (with op amps perhaps) to reduce the voltage but keep the current high and be more cost effective?

32 bits is far more precision than I need so even if the range becomes more like 0-0.003V that is acceptable.

Comment: Use a lot of cheap, lower value resistors in series to make a big resistor.

Comment: Before you design your first prototype I suggest you to read norm UL 60950 for your own safety.

Comment: Is the problem that the current is at  high potential relative to ground, or that the current is small relative to the converter error currents?   Does a battery-powered current monitor that sends its measurements via bluetooth to a cell  phone app fit the need?

Comment: "When I plan out a voltage divider circuit to work with this ADC....", you do need a shunt, not a divider if you want to measure the current. Post a schematics of what you have done. I would rather buffer the shunt voltage with a very high 100G electrometer opamp, not a cheap way.

Answer (score 0):

A shunt of 2M would produce 2V for 1uA. The series resisor limits the current into the opamp. If accidentally a voltage of 15kV is applied on input, then a current of 15kV/100MOhm = 15uA flows into the opamp.

> When either input of the ADA4530-1 exceeds one of the supply rails by
> more than 300 mV, the input ESD diodes become forward-biased and large
> amounts of current begin to flow through them. Without current
> limiting, this excessive fault current causes permanent damage to the
> device. If the inputs are expected to be subject to overvoltage
> conditions, insert a resistor in series with each input to limit the
> input current to 10 mA maximum. However, consider the resistor thermal
> noise effect on the entire circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVY0dG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I would be tempted to use an electrostatic divider. Depends on the mechanical setup.